# Django south datamigrations not running post saves

Tags: django, database, postgresql, database-migration, django-south

I am using django south data-migrations to update data in new tables after schema-migrations that create some new tables. I have written some post-save methods on existing tables to update data on newly created tables. For this, I am using data-migrations and in forward method, I am saving existing table rows so that in post-saves, new tables will get data populated.

However, the post saves dont run after running the data migrations. 
One way is to call the post-save function directly from forward method in datamigrations. But south documentations recommends that you should use orm objects to freeze the state. But in post-save methods, we will be using these models normally. Another way is to copy same code in migration but that way, everytime I make changes in post-save method, I also need to update code in datamigration forward method.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Migration files are just Python modules. You can always import code from other parts of the project hence reusing logic.

That however is a slippery slope because:

Lets say you have a migration which migrates database from state X to state Y (and backwards). Now lets say this migration reuses some code from `foo.py`. Now after some time you need to change your db state from state Y to state Z. If again you reuse some logic from `foo.py`, then you can no longer execute your first migration on a fresh db since some logic is shared between 2 migrations.

If you leave the migration code completely independent, it will make it much easier to maintain many migrations in a long run, even though it can introduce some code duplication.